# nginx config add location lead error

Tags: nginx

I met a problem about Nginx really make me confused.
if I set the server as blow :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /usr/project/exchange/front/build;
    index index.html;
    location = /{
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

if I add location / in the server. the page shows error.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /usr/project/exchange/front/build;
    index index.html;
    location = /{
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
    }
```

}

That's really make confused. Nginx match the url from =/ to /?Why add location / leads to mistake?

Comment: The modified configuration block sends the request for `/index.html` to `proxy_pass`.

Comment: what should I should If I want the index.html not go to location /

Comment: Either you create another specific location (e.g. `location = /index.html`) or use a more general solution such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586112/nginx-unable-to-serve-the-node-js-post-requests/43586922#43586922).